# Cygwin crontab navigate to phpwebpage

Tags: internet-explorer, cron, cygwin

I'm trying execute the following in crontab:
I want to open internet explorer (because it's the only browser installed on the system) and let it navigate to a webpage so a phpscript is executed.
After a few minutes I want to execute a script that closes the internet explorer process. (Because I don't want it to hog up memory as more browsers will be opened during the day).

Is this possible in cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible! :-)

In crontab, set this (adjust the times according to how much it should run):

```
* * * * * '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe' https://somesite.com/test/test.php
```

Create a batch script, put it somewhere, let's say in c:\scripts\killIE.bat with the following content:

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq [username]" /IM iexplore.exe
exit
```

(replace [username] with your username.

Let it run every hour or w/e you want:

```
0 * * * * '/cygdrive/c/scripts/killIE.bat'
```